# Find arc length of implicit function

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives

[Result of integrating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5xAR.png) I've been trying to find the arc length of the following function:

$e^y=\frac{e^x+1}{e^x-1}$

from $x = a$ to $x = b$. 
I've tried designating $y$, but it doesn't seem to work. I would really appreciate your help

Comment: You may call that an "implicit function" but it's just a small step away from being a very explicit function. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: So, i took natural log of both sides, designated y and put the function into the formula for arc length, but i don't really understand what the borders of integration would be.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `from x=a to x=b`?

Comment: Now i get it. But i'm having another issue. Integral calculators say that this integral cannot be calculated, so i wonder whether it's my mistake in building the function.

Comment: I pinned the result to the question

Comment: You should be integrating $\sqrt{(dy/dx)^2+1}$, not $\sqrt{y^2+1}$.

Comment: You are missing a derivative somewhere. Recheck the [arc length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating).

Comment: What are you integrating????

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, i got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $y = $ ln$(\frac{e^x + 1}{e^x-1})$. Then $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{e^x -1}{e^x + 1} * \frac{{e^{2x} - e^x -e^{2x} - e^x}}{(e^x -1)^2} = -2\frac{e^x}{(e^x -1)(e^x +1)} = -2\frac{e^x}{e^{2x} -1}$.

Now, letting $y(x)$ be our curve and $l$ its length, $l(y) = \int_a^b \sqrt{1 + (\frac{dy}{dx})^2} dx$.

Then we have now $l(y) = \int_a^b \sqrt{1 + \frac{4e^{2x}}{e^{4x} - 2e^{2x} +1}}dx=\int_a^b \sqrt{\frac{e^{4x} +2e^{2x} + 1}{e^{4x} - 2e^{2x} +1}}dx=$ $ \int_a^b \sqrt{\frac{(e^{2x} +1)^2}{(e^{2x} -1)^2}}dx = \int_a^b \frac{e^{2x} +1}{e^{2x} -1}dx$.

Now put $u = e^{2x} -1$ Then $du = 2e^{2x}dx,$ or, $dx = \frac{du}{2(1+u)}$. For limits of integration, when $x = a, u = e^{2a} -1$, and when $x=b, u = e^{2b} -1$.

Then our integral becomes $l(y) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{e^{2a} -1}^{e^{2b} -1}\frac{u+2}{u(1+u)}du = \frac{1}{2}\int_{e^{2a} -1}^{e^{2b} -1}\frac{1}{1+u} + \frac{2}{u(1+u)}du$.

Now, you can split up the integrand into two integrals. The first is quite simple, and the second is a routine application of partial fractions decomposition.

Comment: Thank you very much, that really helped.

Comment: No problem, Jack!